# c# sharpdevelop , drawing rectangle or circle and fill it with color #fffffff

Tags: c#, drawing, draw, system.drawing, sharpdevelop

c# sharpdevelop , drawing rectangle or circle and fill it with colour `#fffffff`

I'm using colour code like this `#ffffff` in my application. I need to draw a rectangle or circle and fill it with a specific colour by code.

Is there are anyway to do that?

```
e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black,55,400,715,20);
```

This code draw black not filled ..

How can I fill it with specific colour using codes like this `#fffffff`?

I google it but I couldn't find anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know C# at all, but I use Java, and its `Graphics` class has a `drawRect` and a `fillRect` method, so see if there is a method called `e.Graphics.FillRectangle(...)`

Comment: I'm not sure .. but for me its important to fill the rectangle by hashcode of color ... I will search ..